# Actualizar valores en la ETL a partir de un idpadre

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

estoy utilizando Pentaho 4.3 para hacer la siguiente transformación:
Desde un excel que contiene datos sobre Municipios y Consejos Populares debo insertar en mi BD los consejos populares. Los municipios ya han sido adicionados con anterioridad. Un municipio tiene varios consejos populares. En el excel aparecen los Municipios con sus consejos populares de la siguiente forma: La columna Mcpio-ConsejoP los trae ambos y se diferencian en que si es un municipio el idpadre de la columna con dicho nombre es el mismo que su número, mientras que si es consejo popular el idpadre es el del municipio al que pertenece. Aquí ilustro con una imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui viene mi pregunta, si desde mi BD logro obtener el iddpt que tienen los Municipios en la BD real, y quiero ponérselos como iddpt a sus hijos tambien, Es posible hacer eso con Pentaho ? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre:
1.- Crear una tabla de referencia con los idpadre y iddpt.
2.- Luego, en otra transformación agregas un "input table" con los datos de la tabla de de referencia creada en (1) y "Microsoft Excel input" que traiga los datos de todos los municipios. A continuación utilizas un "Stream value lookup" para agregar el "iddpt" a los datos que vienen desde el "Microsoft Excel input".
2.- En el (2) te quedaran dos columnas iddpt, pero para solucionarlo yo utilizaría "select rename value" elimino con esto el primer "iddpt" (Es el que tendría los datos en blanco) y solo dejo el último que contendría todos los espacios llenos.

PD: Como recomendación la tabla de referencia la dejaría con una transformación para que se actualice cada vez que corras el JOB con el fin de que siempre te salgan actualizados los datos de la segunda transformación.